# Unexpected data-leak in a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, memory-leaks

Recently I started making a certain game in Python called Robbery Clicker. My project uses `tkinter` and has worked relativity well recently.

Essentially, the code shown below would run after being called by a button widget on the GUI:

```
def auto1():
    global coins
    global item1_auto
    if coins >= 250:
        coins -= 250
        runauto1()
        item1_auto = 1
        click1["state"] = DISABLED
        click1.update()
        click1_auto.config(state=DISABLED)

def runauto1():
    global coins
    global item1_sleep
    global item1
    global item1_cost
    click1.after(int(item1_sleep * 1000), runauto1)
    click1.after(int(item1_sleep * 1000), do1())
```

After implementing this code, however, a memory leak occurs immediately after clicking the button, and about 10 seconds after it resolves, it will cause a non-resolvable memory leak.

My whole code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/pHwZFwZV

Comment: What's needed is an [mre], not your **whole code** (or a link to it), nor two snippets without enough information in them for anyone to determine anything.

Comment: alright, Ill do that. Thanks.

Comment: I am actually unable to recreate this issue. I realize though that it is most likely not an issue with the 2 definitions listed in my problem, but an issue with the action being repeated. This means that my main program is required to solve this issue. Sorry!

Comment: I understand. I'm a little skeptical the program has anything to do with `tkinter`, because memory leaks are very rare and it's been around for a long time and has be largely debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least part of the problem is this: `click1.after(int(item1_sleep * 1000), do1())` You are *immediately* calling `do1()` rather than putting it in a queue. It's the same as if you did `result=do1(); click1.after(int(item1_sleep * 1000), None)`. If that causes `runauto1` to be called, you'll quickly create a recursion error.

Comment: how would I fix this?

Comment: @AriesNinja: do it the same way as your other use of after: use `do1` rather than `do1()`